Given an input value returns values like 1050, 1150, 1250, 1350, 1450,
I'm developing a C++ algorithm that, given a float number as input, it returns its closest value to number ending in 50. Sorry, i don't know how to explain it better. With examples I mean, I need these numbers: 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, etc.
In other words, if the input value is between, i.e., [1050, 1100), it will return 1050, but
if the value is between [1100, 1150], it will return 1150.
So, this is my algorithm with only works when input values are equal or greater than 1000.0:

Divide input value by 100.0.
Take fraction part
If faction part is greater or equal to 0.0 and less than 0.5 then add one to integer part.
Multiply integer part by 100.
To the result add 50.

When the input is 701.272 it returns 850.0, but it should return 750.0.
Maybe the problem is divide and multiple by 100 if the input number is less than 1000.
How can I fix this algorithm?

You're pretty much there apart from step 3.  You want to round down if between 0 and 0.5, round up if between 0.5 and 1.  One bit to be cautious of when rounding if exactly 0.5; some languages use bankers' rounding where 50% of the time the number's rounded up, the other 50% they're rounded down (based on whether the integer part is odd or even / resulting in the rounded number always being even).  I don't think C++ does that, but not sure... C# does.  More info: https://wiki.c2.com/?BankersRounding

Can you share the implementation such that others can check it for problems?

Actually, the problem is pretty simple and the only values you have to specifically care about are 0 and any exact multiple of 100, because you want to round that down.
For every other number, it's just the full hundred of the number (for instance 1134.567 -> 1100) and then add 50. Ie, any every number that is strictly greater than 100 and strictly less than 200, your desired result is 150.


function calc(x) {
  if (x === 0) return 50;
  if (x % 100 === 0) return x - 50;
  return Math.floor(x / 100) * 100 + 50;
}

let tests = [0, 1, 49, 50, 51, 99, 100, 101, 149, 150, 151]

for (let t of tests)
  console.log(t, calc(t));



Not 100% sure what you expect with input 0. I currently assumed 50. But if you want to handle it analogous to 100, 200, ... the answer would proably be -50 and you could remove the special handling of 0
EDIT Sorry I missread your rounding condition (didn't see the round parenthesis in [1050, 1100)) so you actually want to round up on an exact multiple of 100. In that case you don't need any special handling at all. You can then just do


function calc(x) {
  return Math.floor(x / 100) * 100 + 50;
}

let tests = [0, 1, 49, 50, 51, 99, 100, 101, 149, 150, 151]

for (let t of tests)
  console.log(t, calc(t));



